# Doing DOM modification the "mediaqueries style" in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, dom

I mainly think i don't find my answer because I don't know what to look for so if you understand what I'm asking for (and you shall) can someone indicate me where to head for.

**I'd like to do like the media queries does in CSS but with HTML element.**

So if the page is this width, display this `<div>...</div>` and if it is larger not displaying it.

**Has it been develop with Laravel and if not what is the main reason not to ?**

Anyone has ever encouter this or can indicate me what to look for on Google pls ?

Comment: PHP (and therefore Laravel) has no ability to determine the viewport size (width/height) of the browser window making the request. Therefore this must be done with client-side languages such as Javascript or CSS.

Comment: @BenSwinburne Perfect answer thank you.

Comment: I'll pop it into an answer then so this question can be marked answered and removed from unanswered lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP (and therefore Laravel) has no ability to determine the viewport size (width/height) of the browser window making the request.

As such, this must be done with client-side languages such as Javascript or CSS.